# Paging ,Sorting from Multi-Dim PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Paging ,Sorting from Multi-Dim PHP Array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            'name' => 'A'
            'Date' => 12-10-1990
            'Grade' => '20D'
            'Level' => 'A10'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            'name' => 'C'
            'Date' => 10-10-1990
            'Grade' => '10C'
            'Level' => 'C10'    
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            'name' => 'B'
            'Date' => 12-11-1995
            'Grade' => '13E'
            'Level' => 'A8'
        )
)
```

Could anybody know how todo this(paging,sorting)? example display in html table:

```
Name (asc/desc) | Date (asc/desc)| Grade (asc/desc)| Level(asc/desc)
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your problem? The sorting should be quite simple with [`usort`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
<?php
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);
?>
```

In this example, we will order by volume descending, edition ascending.
We have an array of rows, but array_multisort() requires an array of columns, so we use the below code to obtain the columns, then perform the sorting.

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
?>

The dataset is now sorted, and will look like this:
volume | edition
-------+--------
    98 |       2
    86 |       1
    86 |       6
    85 |       6
    67 |       2
    67 |       7
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the usort function to sort your array.

Imagine that you want to order by 'name':

```
$sortedArray=usort($array,'cmpname');

function cmpname($arr1,$arr2){
    $nameA=$arr1['name'];
    $nameB=$arr2['name'];
    if ($nameA == $nameB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($nameA > $nameB) ? +1 : -1;
}
```

And then you can do the pagination returning the desired number of items using the function array_slice.